# Uncaught ReferenceError: clickWorld is not defined -- Function not defined?

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

Ok, so i have been coding in javascript for about 3 hours and i'm allready stuck.  It looks so simple, but, whenever i run and click on "Hello" i get an error saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: clickWorld is not defined". I did some google searches and found a few tricks i.e. windows.onload and placing the script tag directly before /body.  Neither solved by problem.  I'm now seeking additional help.  Here is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
</head>

<div id="javatest" onclick="clickWorld()">Hello</div>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
function clickWorld()
    {
    alert("BANG");
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I really appreciate the help as i can't move on in my learning until this is solved.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use an anonymous function with `window.onload`, which should correctly be written like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    alert("BANG");
};
```

By putting it inside the `window.onload` like that you make it so it's out of scope - essentially your `div` can't 'see' the javascript. For your purposes, you probably don't want the window.onload there at all - it's unnecessary. All you need inside your `script` tag is:

```
function clickWorld() {
    alert("BANG");
}
```

You also need to move your `div` from between the `head` and `body` tags - it should be inside the `body` tag.

If you want multiple functions inside your `script` tag, just add them like this:

```
function someFunc1() {
    // Do stuff
}

function someFunc2() {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: what if i wanted to have multiple functions? Would i just use the             'windows.unload = functionName' multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
window.onload = function () {
    function clickWorld() {
        alert("BANG");
    }
}
```

Use

```
function clickWorld() {
    alert("BANG");
}
```

Additionaly

**Put your div in `body`, currently your div is in `head` section**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/J4dkz/)